# Postgres : Selecting duplicates with more than one unique second column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a Postgres query to find all the items in column A that have duplicates where column B has at least 2 unique entries.
For instance :

Data Set

```
Column A | Column B
       1 |        2
       1 |        2
       1 |        3
       4 |        5
       4 |        5
       6 |        7
```

Desired Result

```
Column A | Column B
       1 |        2
       1 |        3
```

Comment: *T'is better to have tried and failed than never have tried at all.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnA ,
                columnB
FROM t
WHERE columnA IN
    (
     SELECT columnA
       FROM t
     GROUP BY columnA
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT columnB) >= 2 
     )
ORDER BY 2;
```